# RecyclerView: position of other object not updating in the arraylist of recyclerviewadapter after deleting an object

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

This is the code for deletion inside recyclerview adapter:

```
      holder.delBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //TODO delete record
                NotesObject note = mDataList.get(position);
                DBHelper db = new DBHelper(holder.itemView.getContext());
                db.deleteNote(note.getUserID(), note.getNoteID());
                mDataList.remove(position);
                //TODO fix bug
//                ArrayList<NotesObject> updateList = new ArrayList<NotesObject>();
//                for(int i=0; i<mDataList.size(); i++){
//                    if(i!=position){
//                        updateList.add(mDataList.get(i));
//                    }
//                }
//                mDataList = updateList;
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
//                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

If I have 2 rows in the recyclerview and I delete the first row, the delete takes place successfully and the recyclerview gets updated perfectly. But now when I go on to delete the 2nd item as well, the item returns position 1 (i.e., its position didn't get updated after item at position 0 was deleted) and the size of list is returned as 1 (i.e., the size got updated after previous deletion) and hence it throws an error for index out of bounds. But if after deleting the first item, I reopen the fragment and then delete the second item, it works fine. I tried manually updating the list indices but that threw an inconsistency error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case somebody faces similar issue in future, this was the solution:
After calling `notifyItemRemoved(position)`, needed to call `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataList.size())`.